# Passing parameters to a PL/SQL function in Oracle apps and calling it on a procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I currently have a working function for encryption of banking data which has to be done before inserting data on the staging table.

But I don't know how to call the function. Below is the function

```
FUNCTION FN_ENCRYPT_3DES(P_SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER INVOICES.SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE
                        P_CARD_NUMBER  ) RETURN RAW IS
    -- --------------------------------------------------
    v_data   VARCHAR2(255);
    v_retval RAW(255);

  BEGIN
    IF P_SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN
      --p_key := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('GD6GTT56HKY4HGF6FH3JG9J5F62FT1');
      v_data := RPAD(P_SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CEIL(LENGTH(P_SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) / 8) * 8, CHR(0));
      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DES3Encrypt(input          => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_data),
                                           key            => G_KEY,
                                           which          => 1,
                                           encrypted_data => v_retval);
      RETURN v_retval;
    ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

  END;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `some_variable := your_function(...);`?

Comment: That might depend on *how* you insert data into the staging table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Check this out in terms of calling the function to the main package not sure is the right one havent checked it my DB SERVER is down:                                                                                                                                                                                                              IF V_SITE_PAYMENT_METHOD = 'Prepaid Card' THEN
                R.INVOICE.SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER := FN_ENCRYPT_3DES();
                ELSE
                  R.INVOICE.SUPPLIER_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER:= NULL;
                  END IF;